# configurable virtual keypad for touchscreen windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtual-keyboard, touchscreen

I need a (preferably open source) virtual keypad for touchscreen on Windows 10 pro. It needs at least 6 customizable keys (W, A, S, D, E, ESC) that can be moved independently around the screen. A virtual mousepad is unneeded, and should not be included (or at least disable-able).